# How can I produce multiple outputs in df.rolling.apply?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200, 10)), columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

============================

     A         B         C  ...         H         I         J
0    0.037608  0.301907  0.392480  ...  0.933584  0.183160  0.704827
1    0.916830  0.419919  0.890444  ...  0.683593  0.004465  0.750646
2    0.631486  0.234803  0.723553  ...  0.960028  0.303452  0.692989
3    0.357510  0.506667  0.928800  ...  0.707072  0.429867  0.993928
4    0.933780  0.083027  0.164354  ...  0.463918  0.291948  0.498712
..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
195  0.229429  0.960220  0.321908  ...  0.825912  0.405020  0.230486
196  0.733413  0.226747  0.707638  ...  0.746275  0.865566  0.579064
197  0.792347  0.440722  0.640206  ...  0.128993  0.161051  0.327097
198  0.399510  0.909695  0.361036  ...  0.604576  0.132304  0.929926
199  0.065853  0.833491  0.526684  ...  0.049173  0.693042  0.196375

============================

def foo(arr):
    return pd.Series([*'XYZ'], index=[*'RST'])

============================

data.agg({'A': foo, 'B': foo})

     A        B      
     R  S  T  R  S  T
0    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
1    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
2    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
3    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
4    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
..  .. .. .. .. .. ..
195  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
196  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
197  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
198  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
199  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
-----------------------------
data.rolling(10).agg({'A': foo, 'B': foo})

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

It seems rolling apply, rolling agg only accept single output, and it also must be float.

Is there any way to produce columns with multiindex like data.agg does?

I need to calculate some statitics on a rolling window, and they share some intermediate variables. So calculate them in one time can save lots of time.

For example, if I want both skewness and kurtosis, then I can reuse the intermediate variables like the second moment, the mean, etc. If I write standalone functions for skewness and kurtosis each, the calculation process will be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(100),
                   'B':np.arange(100,10001,100), 
                   'C':np.arange(1000,100001,1000)})

df.rolling(3).agg(['max','min','std'])
```

Output:

```
     A                 B                      C                
   max  min  std     max    min    std      max     min     std
0  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
2  2.0  0.0  1.0   300.0  100.0  100.0   3000.0  1000.0  1000.0
3  3.0  1.0  1.0   400.0  200.0  100.0   4000.0  2000.0  1000.0
4  4.0  2.0  1.0   500.0  300.0  100.0   5000.0  3000.0  1000.0
5  5.0  3.0  1.0   600.0  400.0  100.0   6000.0  4000.0  1000.0
6  6.0  4.0  1.0   700.0  500.0  100.0   7000.0  5000.0  1000.0
7  7.0  5.0  1.0   800.0  600.0  100.0   8000.0  6000.0  1000.0
8  8.0  6.0  1.0   900.0  700.0  100.0   9000.0  7000.0  1000.0
9  9.0  7.0  1.0  1000.0  800.0  100.0  10000.0  8000.0  1000.0
```

Comment: You didn't get it, I mean I want multiple outputs in a single function. For example, if I want both skewness and kurtosis, then I can reuse the intermediate variables like the second moment, the mean, etc. If I write standalone functions for  skewness and kurtosis each, the calculation process will be redundant.